# Doing a simple server-side REST service in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to make a very simple REST controller in my react.js application that sends back a hard-coded array of strings.  I know there's tutorials out there about react and spring, but I'm not ready to get into all that yet.  Is there a way I can do this just with react?
Here's what I've written so far (in src/controllers/FetchUsers.js)

```html
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export const FetchUsers = async () => {
    console.log('fetching user names');
    let results = [];
    results = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
    return { results };
}


// ========================================
export default FetchUsers;
```

Comment: React is a browser / client-side UI framework and would not be suitable to build a RESTful API. Are you wanting to write code to *get* data from an existing API?

Comment: do you want mock api call?

Comment: yea, it would just be a stub for now, so I can tinker with calling rest services. I'm using a hard-coded file at the moment, but it would demo better if I can have a bit of logic on the server side.

Comment: How are you using a hard-coded file at the moment?

Comment: .....
url = "/static/triggerRealityCheck.json";
.....
if (url !== null)
{
    const resource = await fetch(url);
    const responseFromServer = await resource.json();
    var msg = responseFromServer.response;
    this.setState({
        response : msg
    });
} ... Then I put response into a dialog.